# Why doesn't this code generate the number 0?

Tags: javascript

Was wondering why my code doesn't generate the number zero, every number is randomly generated from 1-9.

What will I need to change to include 0-9 range.

```
function GenerateCaptcha() {
var chr1=Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
```

Many Thanks

Comment: `Math.ceil` rounds to the next upper integer value. but you could get zero if random returns a zero, which is possible.

Comment: Oh i see, that's great to know. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: func fact, even your current code has a `1 in 2**54` chance to generate a `0`. because that are the odds for every distinct value generated by `Math.random()`, and one of them is exactly `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the super short version `~~(Math.random() * 10)` to generate a number between 0-9
`Math.random() * 10)` will return a number with a bunch of decimals ex:`4.324843245` So what we can do is to convert it to a int, the easiest way to do this in javascript is with `~~` it's exactly the same as `parseInt`

```js
console.log(~~(Math.random() * 10))
console.log(parseInt(Math.random() * 10))
console.log(Math.random() * 10)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I don't know why I'm getting downvoted. Thought I asked a genuine question. Thank you for helping me though x

Comment: @UrbanOzzy dont worry about it, I know it's hard to find what you want when you dont have much experience/is new. It's just that you could find the solution fast if you google it

Answer (score 4):

From the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

> The Math.ceil() function always rounds a number up to the next largest whole number or integer.

This means, if you get a number between 0 and 1, it will be rounded to 1.

You could leave it as is, or use [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) instead.

Or even better, [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), as [Levi Johansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1678383/levi-johansen) suggested. This will round to the closest integer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';` with `Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)+ '';`

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)`

Comment: @Thomas, correct, we can consider this as well, thanks for update :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.floor()` for generating 0 as one of the random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To generate 0 you need to use `Math.floor()` in place of `Math.ceil`.

For Example

```
function GenerateCaptcha() {
var chr1=Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
```

`Math.ceil` gives 1 if it's below 1 i.e. 0.xxx

`Math.floor` gives 0 when number is. greater than 0 and less than 1. i.e. from 0.0 to 0.99